# Python list doesn't give the rigth result

Tags: python, list, function

i am trying to create a list with all of the paths from the nodes, but my list only contains the first path over and over again even though i wrote a range function that should go over all of the nodes. Can someone tell me where i made a mistake?

This is the input:

```
Nodes:

1   (5,13)  (1,3)  [3] 
2   (15,5)  (2,1)  
3   (8,11)  (2,4)  [1,4,5,6]
4   (11,3)  (3,3)  [1]
5    (3,7)  (2,2)   
6   (20,6)  (1,1)  [2,3,7]
7   (15,8)  (3,4)  [1,2,4]
```

As you can see some nodes dont have a thirt index, that means that they can access all of the paths [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

The right list should look like this:

```
[[3], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,4,5,6], [1], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [2,3,7], [1,2,4]]

print (all_paths)
```

is giving [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] and print(len(nodes)) is giving 7, they are working fine but **print(paths) is giving [[3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3]]** which is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
all_paths = []
for i in range (len(nodes)):
    all_paths.append(i+1)

def index_in_list(nodes):
    for i in range (len(nodes)):
        if (len(nodes[i])) < 3:
            return False
        else:
            return True

paths = []
for i in range (len(nodes)):
           if index_in_list(nodes) is True:
               paths.insert(i,nodes[0][2])
           else:
               paths.insert([all_paths])
```

**i tried to fix it with a loop but now my paths list is staying empty**

```
def index_in_list(nodes):
    paths = []
while i < (len(nodes)):
      if (len(nodes[i])) < 3:
          paths.insert(i,[all_paths]
          i = i + 1
      else:
          paths.insert(i,[all_paths])
          i = i + 1
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code dies from `nodes` being undefined, and there is no clear execution trace to show where the results begin to depart from your expectations.

Comment: I'll be happy to look at your update, once you've supplied the MRE.  Don't expect us to write a driver program, supply the input example, and correct your syntax errors.

Comment: Well i made the input more clearer and there are no syntax errors according to python, i have read what a MRE is supposed to be and i think i did that. Maybe i am missing something since english is not my first language and i am a beginner, but this is all of my code with the nodes as input and the right list that should come out of it.

Comment: Your last code section, the attempted fix,  is a two-line function followed by a `while` loop that fails due to undefined symbols.  I suspect that you need to indent the `while` to bring all of that code within the function.  There is still no MRE; please read my first comment again.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the `index_in_list` function is behaving differently than you expect it to. Whenever python encounters a return statement in a function, it will exit that function and give back the value that was written along with the `return`. In this case you always start to look at the length of `nodes` at index 0 and then the function returns True. At the point in you code where you call the function this will therefore always be True and you will always insert `nodes[0][2]`, which is [3]

Answer (score -1):

I took a quick scan over your code, and it appears that the problem may be here:

```
       if index_in_list(nodes) is True:
           paths.insert(i,nodes[0][2])
       else:
           paths.insert([all_paths])
```

`index_in_list` returns immediately on the result of nodes[0], which is always `True` for your data set; it never checks the other nodes.  The code above then inserts that same `[3]` index into `paths` multiple times.  Nothing in your logic moves considers any other node.

Comment: so how can it go over the other nodes too? i have tried adding 1 to the node after the insertion but it didnt work

Comment: You write a loop to do what you intended.  Any tutorial on examining a list shows you how to do this.  Very simply, you *cannot* return failure until you've examined all of the nodes.  You have to pull `return False` outside of the loop.

Comment: i have updated a function with a loop but this time it doesnt take anything, can you have a look at it